# What are the best NLP sentence alignment tools?

Tags: machine-translation, sentences, tools

Which tools are worthwhile for aligning sentences from pairs of paragraphs of source and target languages.

Comment: https://github.com/rsennrich/Bleualign

Answer (score 2):

There is [hunalign](https://github.com/danielvarga/hunalign) available from github. It is the current standard tool for multilingual aligned corpora.